# App scripts trigger to send message on slack via a webhook creates duplicate triggers

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have set a trigger to run 9am daily and post to the channel in slack via a webhook, although set to run everyday I am getting duplicate returns in a channel.

Here is the function:

```
function setTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendBirthdayMessage')
  .timeBased()
  .everyDays(1)
  .atHour(9)
  .nearMinute(00)
  .create()
}
```

What ends up happening is that it runs on multiple times.

[image]

Is there a way to check if a trigger for that day has already been executed before proceeding to init a new trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your screenshot show is that there are 3 triggers in your Apps Script project (not three executions of the same trigger, three different triggers). So most likely, the same function is being called 3 times a day.

You can list the triggers in your project with `ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()`. This returns a list of [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger). And then you call call the `getHandlerFunction()` method on them to see what function they're gonna run ([doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger#getHandlerFunction())).

Also, you can delete a trigger with `ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(THE_TRIGGER)` (not its name, the Trigger object itself).